# Infinitely many rational numbers between two different real numbers

Tags: real-analysis

how to show that between any two distinct real numbers there are infinitely many rational numbers?  do we need to use the fact that a real number is an equivalent class of cauchy sequence of rational numbers?

Answer (score 6):

If you know that between any two real numbers there exists at least one rational number, you can conclude the result from there. Take $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $x\neq y$. Take a rational number $q_{1}\in (x,y)$. Since $q_{1}\neq x$, by similar reasoning we find a rational number $q_{2}\in (x,q_{1})$. In this fashion we obtain inductively for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ a rational number $q_{n+1}\in (x,q_{n})$. In particular, $q_{k}\in (x,y)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so between $x$ and $y$ there are infinitely many rational numbers.

To show that for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ so that $x\neq y$ we find a rational number $q\in (x,y)$, we can use the fact that each real number is an equivalent class of Cauchy sequences.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted

Comment: @AlecTeal Seems like the same two guys just went on a downvoting spree

Comment: This is way too funny hahaha :D

Comment: There really should be some oversight on this. It's not a big deal, but downvoting should require at least a justification by way of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If you can show there is one $q_1\in (a,b)$ where $a\neq b\in \mathbb{R}$, then you can show there are two: say a $q_2\in (a, q_1)\subset (a,b)$.  Then, you can find a third $q_3\in (a, q_2)$...

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Please someone explain...

Comment: It looks like this is a recurrent theme today --people downvoting for no good reason, and without explanations.

Comment: @ClementC., thanks for the comment.  It's not so much that I care about the "internet points" it's just frustrating to think that someone believes your hint/answer is for some reason bad.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \not =b$. Without loss of generality suppose that $a<b$, then there exists a positive $c$ such that $b-a=c$. Now there exists a rational number $n> \frac{1}{c}$. Then $nc>1$ which implies that $n(b-a)>1$. Thus $nb-na>1$ so there exists an integer $r$ such that $na<r<nb$, hence $a< \frac{r}{n}<b$. Therefore there exists a rational number between any two real numbers. So there is a rational number $x$ such that $a<x<\frac{a+b}{2}$. Likewise there exists a rational number $x_1$ such that $\frac{a+b}{2}<x_1<b$ then we have that $a<x<x_1<b$. There exists another rational number $x_2$ such that $x_1<x_2<\frac{x_1+b}{2}$. Then there exists a rational number $x_3$ such that $\frac{x_1+b}{2}<x_3<b$. Again there exists another rational number $x_4$ such that $\frac{x_3+b}{2}<x_4<b$. Continuing in this fashion infintiely many times will result in an infinite number of rational numbers such that $a<x<x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<\cdots<b$.

My approach looking for suggestions on improvement.